# Python bind cmd.exe to port

Tags: python, sockets, netcat

How do I bind cmd.exe onto a port in Python? I want to do the same thing as
Netcats "-e" argument. So the equivilent in Netcat would be:

```
netcat -l -p 8080 -e cmd.exe
```

But I want to code it myself in Python, without using Netcat. So how is this
done? Are there any functions/modules that can do this? How can I convert the process (cmd.exe) and make it a server so it runs on a port?

Answer (score 0):

1. Listen to a port
2. Read the input
3. Pipe it to cmd.exe
4. Send back the output

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this, except you would have to change it into running on Windows (this example runs fine on Linux):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import subprocess

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(("", 9999))
s.listen(1)
(conn, address) = s.accept()

p = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash"], 
                     stdin=conn, stdout=conn, stderr=conn)
```

If you run this program, and then in another terminal use netcat to connect to port 9999, you'll have a bash shell to play with. Be careful not to let the whole internet get access to this port, that would give anyone instant shell access on your machine :-)